# How to cast Any to a List in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

When I try to cast `Any` to a `List` like in the example below I get '`Unchecked cast: Any! to List`' warning. Are there any workarounds to this kind of problem?

```
val x: List<Apples> = objectOfTypeAny as List<Apples>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is "just" a warning saying that it's not 100% safe just to cast. The better option would be:

```
if (objectOfTypeAny is List<*>) {
        val a: List<Apples> = objectOfTypeAny.filterIsInstance<Apples>()
        ...
}
```

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html for details.

Comment: That wouldn't remove the warning, doesn't make the cast checked, and in fact doesn't even compile.

Comment: 1. I didn't insult anyone. 2. I tried it out: `Error:(7, 31) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is Any but List<Apples> was expected`. See by yourself: http://rextester.com/ISWQP14284

Comment: @JBNizet I've to apologise. Your are perfectly right, the inner statement doesn't compile. It does in my code, because I gave the compiler a hint what the type is. I will correct this. Sorry again.

Answer (score 3):

Except ignoring the warning (or improving the design to avoid the cast), no.

This warning means that the cast can succeed at runtime even though the list is not actually a `List<Apples>`, but contains something other than `Apples`.

It exists because generics are not reified in Java. Generics work with type erasure. they're a compile-time safety net, not a runtime safety net.

Comment: any other way to cast ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution case for android Serializable to ArrayList:**

ModJsonAndDb - your class

```
private fun serializableToArrayList(obj: Serializable?): ArrayList<ModJsonAndDb>? {
    return if (obj is ArrayList<*>) {
        ArrayList(obj.filterIsInstance<ModJsonAndDb>())
    } else {
        null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Add:

    inline fun <reified T> List<*>.asListOfType(): List<T>? =
        if (all { it is T })
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            this as List<T> else
            null

2. Use:

    val list: List<YouType> = someAnyList?.asListOfType<YouType>()
```

Answer (score 0):

As an extension function I came to following solution:

```
fun <X> Any?.mapToTypedList(desiredListElementType: Class<X>): MutableList<X?> {
    if (this == null) throw IllegalStateException("Provided object is null")
    if (this !is List<*>) throw IllegalStateException("Provided object not of type List")
    val castedList: List<*> = this
    if (castedList.any { it != null && !desiredListElementType.isInstance(it) }) throw IllegalStateException("Found element in list which is not of correct type $desiredListElementType")
    return castedList.map { when(it) {
        null -> null
        else -> desiredListElementType.cast(it)
    } }.toMutableList()
}
```

Usage (*x* is of any type but actually contains a list of String):

```
val castedList: MutableList<String?> = x.mapToTypedList(String::class.java)
```

Comment: Imo the naming for this would trip a reader into thinking its _cheap_ and maybe even backed by the original list. But it requires a full iteration and creates a new independent list. So before copy-pasting this code, I would improve the naming and remove the `Cast` part of it. Maybe `mapToTypedList`.

Comment: I agree. The naming in the code snippet is misleading as the user will never receive the original list but a typed copy. I like your suggestion so I'll edit my answer and use it. Thanks for the comment.